# Como reemplazar la session en web asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

A ver, le explicare con más detalle lo ocurrido. Yo tengo un texbox y un button; lo que yo quiero es ingresar datos al texbox y cuando presiono click en el botón me redireccione a otra página obteniendo el valor de ese texbox.  Para eso estoy sesión que almacenen y luego en el otra ventana que me va redireccionar ya mostrarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen de mi codebing cuando presiono el click en el botón .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para obtener el valor de esa sesión y para mostrar en un texbox lo que hago es en load(), como este código de mi webform2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora cuando ejecuto el aplicativo, ingreso en mi webform1.aspx y coloco el nombre en el texbox: **"nombre1"** si me redirecciona al webform2.aspx y si se muestra mi **"nombre1"**.

Ahora el problema es que cuando abro en otra pestaña y coloco el webform1.aspx y coloco en el texbox **nombre2** si me direccionamiento a la otra pagina y si sale el segundo nombre que coloqué ahora vuelvo a la pestaña anterior y actualizo la página el nombre ha cambiado y ese es el problema.

¿Cómo pudiera que no se cambie o que método es para reemplazar la sesión?, ya que lo que le mostre es algo pequeño pero acorde a mi pregunta ya que en mi sistema pasa lo mismo y yo quisiera tener el nombre que se colocó, imagínense que un usuario ingresa y registra algo y está bien registra con su primer nombre que ingresó pero luego ingresa con su otro usuario y registra todo. Ahora en la sesión lo va coger ya con el segundo usuario y no con el primero y causaría problemas.

Este es el Código de WebForm1

**Front-End**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Back-End**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["usuario"] = TextBox1.Text;

            Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
        }
```

Código Webform2

**Front-End**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Back-End**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                if (Session["usuario"].ToString() == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl1.Text = Session["usuario"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según comentas el usuario inicia sesión con cuentas diferentes con el mismo navegador? Eso no debería ser posible o lo he entendido mal?.

Comment: @AnonimoPer no es eso , sino que yo agarro la session['username'] para que agarre el usuario y asi saber que es lo que hace pero imaginate
que un usuario ingrese en un navegador y se logee y ya tiene la session registrada por ese usuario pero el usuario lo que hace sin cerrar session habre la misma pagina se logea pero con otro usuario
y al momento de registrar claro que se va tomar el usuario que ultimo que ingreso eso es uno de los problema de las sessiones quisiera saber si hay otro tipo para que no ocurra eso

Comment: @AnonimoPer no se si me entiendo doc.

Comment: @AnonimoPer edite mi pregunta mas especifica

Comment: En tu condicion, no deberia ser `if (Session["0"].ToString() == null)` ?

Comment: @SamirLlorente tienes razón. listo puede ver

Comment: ok amigo tu estas haciendo algo mal aquí, cada vez que alguien entra a la página debes comprobar si ya estaba conectado

Comment: @LPZadkiel SI lo hice bueno con el ultima si es vacio que lo redireccione a la pagina anterior

Comment: si puede volver a iniciar sesión sin cerrar la anterior entonces no lo hiciste o bien tienes mal la lógica, el objeto `Session` se crea a nivel de usuario, es decir, se crea un objeto `Session` navegador - servidor, esto quiere decir que si abre otra pestaña el objeto sigue existiendo, incluso, si cierras todas las pestañas de tu aplicación web y la abres de nuevo el objeto sigue existiendo, este objeto deja de existir cuando el navegador se cierra

Comment: la lógica que debes seguir es: `Session["0"] != null` redireccionar a página de inicio (o página anterior); `Session["0"] == null` redireccionar a página de inicio de sesión. Lo que guardes dentro de `Session["0"]` vendría a ser relevante para la interacción con la base de datos, por ejemplo, ir a buscar los datos del usuario guardado en `Session` o ir a guardar los datos asociados al usuario guardado en `Session`. Cabe mencionar que cuando haces el desconectar debes limpiar el usuario que guardaste en `Session`

Comment: Consulta , lo que quieres conseguir es que en el mismo explorador tener 2 pestañas abiertas de la misma página con diferente session?,
o lo que quieres es..abrir la primera pestaña con una sesión luego abrir otra pestaña con otra sesión de tal forma que si regresas a la pestaña 1 la recargues y ver la sesión iniciada en la pestaña 2.?

Comment: He editado mi respuesta según tus nuevas aclaraciones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como ha comentado @Flxtr, tienes un problema para comprobar si el usuario ya ha estado autenticado. En la mayoría de las webs que requieren de logueo no permiten poder trabajar con dos o más usuarios a la vez desde un mismo navegador. Si este es tu caso ya te han dado una buena solución. Otra opción similar sería usar cookies.

En el caso de que esta solución no se adapte a tus necesidades porque por cualquier motivo necesitas poder trabajar con distintos usuarios en un mismo navegador, puedes crear el nombre de las sesiones dinámicamente para cada usuario. Te pongo un ejemplo:

Supongamos que tenemos una web con un logueo simple. Se pide un nombre de usuario y una contraseña, se comprueba en base de datos que este usuario existe y según la respuesta, lo dejamos acceder o no.

Se me ocurre que aproveches esta consulta para obtener el código de identificador único del usuario de tu base de datos y utilizarlo para crear dinámicamente el nombre de la variable de sesión:

```
int id = // identificador que obtenemos de la bbdd.
if (Session["user" + id] == null)
    Session["user" + id] = TxUsuario.Value.Trim().ToUpper();
```

Así, en el caso de que el usuario no se hubiera logueado anteriormente, crea la variable de sesión. Y si ya había estado logueado no hacemos nada, ya que la variable de sesión ya existe.

Pero para que esto funcione, también debes propagar este id por toda la aplicación (por ejemplo, puedes enviar del formulario ***login*** al formulario ***home*** este id por url).

> *www.tudominio.com/home?d=123*

o

> *www.tudominio.com/home/123*

Luego para volver a recuperar el nombre del usuario, simplemente vuelves a crear dinámicamente el nombre de la variable de sesión:

```
int id = // identificador obtenido desde otro formulario mediante url.
string txUsuario = Session["user" + id].ToString();
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y que te sea de utilidad.

**EDICIÓN A PARTIR DE TU ACLARACIÓN**

Si ajustamos un poco el ejemplo que te di, podemos adaptarlo a lo que quieres. Haremos este cambio en tu evento *click* del WebForm1:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["usuario" + TextBox1.Text] == null)
        Session["usuario" + TextBox1.Text] = TextBox1.Text;

    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?u=" + TextBox1.Text);
}
```

Con esto lo que hacemos es crear una "variable de sesión única" para este usuario, y enviamos el nombre por url a WebForm2.

Y una vez en WebForm2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string u = Request.QueryString["u"] == null ? "" : Request.QueryString["u"].ToString();

    if (Session["usuario" + u] == null)
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
    else
        lbl1.Text = Session["usuario" + u].ToString();    
}
```

De esta forma, en WebForm2 comprobamos que recibimos por url el valor ***u*** y lo usamos para crear la "variable de sesión única". Si no existiera lo enviamos de nuevo a WebForm1.aspx.

Quizás esta no es la forma más correcta de hacerlo, ya que utilizando simplemente el valor ***u*** que recibimos por url tenemos el nombre, pero como ejemplo para clarificar un poco las cosas está bien.

A demás, en el ejemplo tampoco lo he hecho pero yo acostumbro a encriptar todo parámetro que envío por url.

Comment: como lo encriptas :O

Comment: Yo suelo usar tripleDES (3DES). Hay muchísima información en la red. Aquí un ejemplo: https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/10/23/encrypt-and-decrypt-plain-string-with-triple-des-in-c/

Comment: yo tambien realizo eso pero en la conexiones de mi sql server pero en variables no he usado

Answer (score 6):

El problema radica en que al ingresar al Login, no tienes una validación para saber si el usuario se encuentra autenticado.

Suponiendo que una vez que el usuario se autentica guardas el nombre del usuario en una variable de sesión `Session["AutenticatedUser"] = TxUsuario.Value.Trim().ToUpper();` (propongo usar nombres conocidos porque `Session["0"]` solo lo conoces tú y se vuelve complicado el mantenimiento, incluso para ti), luego, en el `Page_Load` del Login.aspx deberás tener algo como esto:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["AutenticatedUser"]))
    {
        //Aquí va el código restante donde haces el login
    }
    else //Si ya está logueado, le haces un redirect a la página de inicio 
    {
        Response.Redirect("MiPaginaDeInicio.aspx");
    }
}
```

De igual forma, cuando haces el Logout al usuario, deberás destruir la variable de sesión para que cuando ingresen al login entre como un usuario nuevo.

Código del Logout.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["AutenticatedUser"] = null;
}
```

Comment: Es mejor usar **Session.Remove("AutenticatedUser");**

Comment: el buen @Flxtr hermano ahora puse tu mismo codigo pero me arroja el siguiente error

Comment: ¿cuál error es el que te da?

Comment: @Flxtr cuando lo ejecuto en el navegador sale un bucle y despues sale localhost se ha caido multiples , eso tan solo me da cuando ejecuto el proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Revisa si tu sesion esta vacia de la siguiente manera

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["0"] as string))
{
    //Codigo
}
```

Comment: el problema no es cerrar la session el problema es lineas arriba

Comment: cuado te logueas que imprime `Session["0"]` en la pagina despues de loguiado y el pagina de login con la sesion abierta

Answer (score 0):

Yo hago lo mismo guardo el ID del usuario en variable de sesión o sino en una cookie sí el cliente desea mantener su sesión iniciada, también me di cuenta del caso que mencionas, para ello hice lo mas simple que se puede hacer, al momento de ir al login, exactamente en su evento **onload** elimino la variable de sesión o en su defecto la cookie, de esta forma ningún usuario va a poder acceder al mismo tiempo que dure la sesión de otro, porque la sesión previa ya se habrá cerrado al momento de abrir el formulario del login.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Request.Cookies["idUserCookie"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("idUserCookie");
                myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            }
        if ((string)Session["IdUser"]   != null)
            Session.Remove("IdUser");
    }
}
```

Comment: voy modificar mi pregunta con tu respuesta para que pueda saber si asi esta bien para ello hare una demostracion

Comment: Claro, dime tienes alguna duda respecto a esta lógica?

Comment: ya la edite mi pregunta

Comment: luis ancantara ya edite hermano

Comment: no entiendo lo que haces, ya te dije la solución es simple, así como esta creo que confundirás mas a las personas que vean tu caso.